# order email send to multiple customer(random customer)

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, magento-1.9.3.8

My problem is **ordered email send to random multiple customers**, i have installed Magento(Magento ver. 1.9.3.8).

when customer **place order**, it will send an order email to random multiple customers. it sends order email to the customer(who order product) + random multiple customers. each and every time Magento send order email to a random customer. I do not have any file or folder in **local**(app\code\local)

I did clear index, Cache Storage Management, manually Cache clear(from var), flush Cache etc..

[image]

I have no idea how to fix it, **Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clear all data of **core_email_queue_recipients** table i got solution.

**message_id** fiels is duplicate in **core_email_queue_recipients** table, so it is send multiple email to **ordered email send to random multiple customers**